# how can I backup and restore of partitions and logical volumes?

Tags: linux, backup, lvm, snapshot

This is my disk scheme

```
sda1                       /boot          ext4
sda2                       /somefiles     ext4
sda3:                                     lvm
    volgroup1/lvolume1     /              ext4
sda4:                                     lvm
    volgroup2/myvolume     /myvolume      ext4
```

1-How can I make a snapshot of sda2 and store it on `volgroup2/myvolume` ?
1.b- How can I restore that partition to original state by using that snapshot?

2-How can I make a snapshot of `volgroup1/lvolume1` and store it on `volgroupe2/myvolume`?
2.b- How can I restore that volume to original state by using that snapshot?

3-Do I need another OS or a live CD to make or restore snapshots of `volgroup1/lvolume1`?

Comment: I generally recommend fsarchiver for making copies of filesystems.

Comment: @FaheemMitha   can it backup and restore root volume when it is mounted?

Comment: Possibly, but you are really better off doing those things when unmounted. I don't really know. I've never tried doing that.